# Simple DSolve example entirely fails in V13, but works in V12.3

Tags: differential-equations

There's a second-order boundary value problem that I've successfully evaluated in V12.3, which for some reason fails to be solved in V13.

```
Assuming[{a>0, b>0, k>0}, DSolve[{u''[x] - 1/u[x]^3 - k u[x] == 0, u'[0] == a, u[0] == b}, u[x], x]]
```

While the solution isn't the prettiest, it's definitely correct in V12.3:

```
{{u(x)->(1/(2 b))(\[Sqrt](-(1/p)(2 a^2 b^2+\[Sqrt](-((a^4 b^4+a^2 (2 b^2-2 b^6 p)+(b^4 p+1)^2) tanh^2(2 Sqrt[p] x-tanh^-1((-a^2 b^2+b^4 (-p)-1)/(2 a b^3 Sqrt[p]))) sech^2(2 Sqrt[p] x-tanh^-1((-a^2 b^2+b^4 (-p)-1)/(2 a b^3 Sqrt[p])))))+cosh(4 Sqrt[p] x-2 tanh^-1((-a^2 b^2+b^4 (-p)-1)/(2 a b^3 Sqrt[p]))) \[Sqrt](-((a^4 b^4+a^2 (2 b^2-2 b^6 p)+(b^4 p+1)^2) tanh^2(2 Sqrt[p] x-tanh^-1((-a^2 b^2+b^4 (-p)-1)/(2 a b^3 Sqrt[p]))) sech^2(2 Sqrt[p] x-tanh^-1((-a^2 b^2+b^4 (-p)-1)/(2 a b^3 Sqrt[p])))))-2 b^4 p+2)))}}
```

Whereas in V13.1, I get the following error message (even if I set `IncludeSingularSolutions -> True`):

> DSolve::bvimp: General solution contains implicit solutions. In the boundary value problem, these solutions will be ignored, so some of the solutions will be lost.
>
> `{}`

Comment: Maple fails with it.

Comment: For the record, v11.2 also solves it.

Comment: If you `FullSimplify` the solution using the assumptions you can reduce the `LeafCount` a little over 20%; however, it is quite slow.

Comment: @user64494 that’s good to know :)

Comment: @HansOlo that’s also cool! I wonder if it’s a syntax thing. i hope it’s not deeper than that

Comment: @BobHanlon that’s helpful! however i’ve also had some good luck reducing it by hand :)